# Id number of employee to be unique in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I  want to make the employee id number to be unique but I don't know where to start. I have a column called idnumber for employee's identifier in different tables in my database.

example admin input 1500960 as idnumber of specific employee and 1500960 should not use it again

Comment: Any auto-increment column will do this.

Comment: customize or admin input is the idnumber I talked about

Comment: If it's a primary key then it is unique. If not, add a unique constraint.

Comment: Like this $table->string('idnumber')->nullable()->unique(); ? and nothing more?

Comment: If that's in your migration, that might be the key. Just check that in the resulting schema it's got a `UNIQUE` index/constraint.

Comment: then I can use the idnumber without using it again for other employee? Thank you

Comment: If you never delete a row, yes. If you do delete rows you'll need to track which IDs were previously issued.

Comment: No, its fine. I also solved this one. Thank you :)

Comment: Do You want To use Like as **EMP-100,EMP-101,EMP-102,**as Series and also it must be unique??